# started rails server, now what?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby on rails and trying to start learning. I'm developing on mac os x. I updated rubygems and rails.

I've started the server and have gotten the rails welcome page but my terminal is hung up. If i quit the terminal the server ends. Here is the text in my terminal right now. the cursor is on a new row directly under the last line so anything i type doesn't do anything if entered(except go to new line).

Is there a command i'm missing to start creating controllers and views in the terminal?

```
Last login: Thu Dec 15 18:11:43 on ttys000
You have mail.
Joe-Blows-MacBook-Pro:~ joeblow$ cd desktop/code/blogg
Joe-Blows-MacBook-Pro:blogg joeblow$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2011-12-15 18:26:35] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-12-15 18:26:35] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10) [universal-darwin10.0]
[2011-12-15 18:26:35] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=25823 port=3000


Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Dec 15 18:26:39 -0600 2011
Served asset /rails.png - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
```

Comment: Have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#hello-rails you are now somewhere around there in the beginner's guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When developing Rails applications, you'll typically have *several* terminals open at once.

This terminal is just for watching the standard output logging from the server. You'll probably want another terminal open with `tail -F /path/to/logs/logs` to see *all* the logs at once, and another terminal open for your editing, `rails generate ...`, `git`, etc. uses. You might have one more open for `script/console` to give you an `irb`-alike interface "inside" your application.

Comment: oooh ok. I guess that makes sense. So basically the initial "rails server" terminal window is so you can Ctr+C to close the server?

Comment: Yes, and give you a convenient way to see some logging information.

Answer (score 0):

Open your browser and go to `http://127.0.0.1:3000`

If you want to be able to use the console run

```
rails server &
```